# Unable to use pool.apply_async to get result

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to use pool.apply_async to do asynchronous processing but it keeps running without returning the result.

```
def myfun(x, y, i ,j):
   z = process data(x, y)
   return i, j, z

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=4)
res = []
for i in range(10):
    x = df.loc[i, 'data']
    for j in range(i+1, 10):
        y = df.loc[j, 'data']
        res.append(pool.apply_async(myfun, (x, y, i, j)))
for i in res:
    print(i.get())
```

How to get the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

you need to `close` the pool and wait for processes to finish using `join`:

```
def myfun(x, y, i ,j):
   z = process data(x, y)
   return i, j, z

from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=4)
res = []
for i in range(10):
    x = df.loc[i, 'data']
    for j in range(i+1, 10):
        y = df.loc[j, 'data']
        res.append(pool.apply_async(myfun, (x, y, i, j)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
for i in res:
    print(i.get())
```

Comment: Try to debug or  add prints to your code to see if the processes are progressing. Maybe you just need to wait a little longer. It depends on what your code does.

I tried to run this code without the logic and it seems to work just fine (replaced x,y and z with dummy variables and removed the process_data method).

Comment: I found the reasons why it didn't work. I need to put down if "__name__ == '__main__':" before "from multiprocessing import Pool". How can it work without adding "__name__ == '__main__':"?